# Maven pack directory with html files into jar

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a simple web app with following structure:

[image: project structure]

I need to pack it into a `jar`.
Here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>L1.1</groupId>
    <artifactId>L1.1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}</outputDirectory>
                    <finalName>server</finalName>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>templates</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>page.html</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.0.M0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.0.M0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I pack it with `Maven`'s `assembly:single` option:
[image: maven option]

But when I run my app with `java -jar server.jar` and pass a request in browser I get:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template "templates/page.html" not found.
```

This happens because a folder `templates` with `page.html` in it is not added to `jar` - I unpacked `server.jar` searched for it, but didn't find.

I googled a lot something like "maven pack resources into jar" or "maven pack html into jar". And the most close article to my issue was:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

I followed instructions in that article - added `<resources>` and rest tags where I outlined my folder and a file that I want to include in `jar` (please see it in `pom.xml` that I wrote above).

But still this folder and `page.html` aren't added.

Please guide me, what I'm doing wrong and how to add `templates` folder with `page.html` in it in `jar`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case spring framework has resource folder under SRC .... And that resource folder contain template folder.

```
Src->resource -> template
```

Comment: Using `jetty` server and Java EE, not `Spring`.